# Como obtener el valor de un objeto en VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Hola en una llamada a la api debo obtener un encabezado

```
this.Header = response.headers["x-pagination"]
```

Eso me devuelve lo siguiente en this.header:

```
{"TotalCount":166,"PageSize":10,"CurrentPage":1,"TotalPages":17,"HasNext":true,"HasPrevious":false}
```

De esto necesito obtener los valores por separado es decir `TotalCount`, `PageSize` etc para llenar otras variables.

He intentado

```
this.header["TotalCount"]
this.header.TotalCount
```

Sin resultados, por favor soy nuevo en vuejs alguien puede aclararme el tema.

Comment: como esta declarado  this.header?

Comment: Esta declarado asi Header:{}

Comment: con esto deberia ser suficiente this.header.TotalCount, pero creo que tu this.header es undefined, compruebalo con console

Comment: puse un console.log(this.Header) y me muestra {"TotalCount":166,"PageSize":10,"CurrentPage":1,"TotalPages":17,"HasNext":true,"HasPrevious":false}

Comment: console.log(this.Header) me devuelve {"TotalCount":166,"PageSize":10,"CurrentPage":1,"TotalPages":17,"HasNext":true,"HasPrevious":false}   y console.log(this.Header.TotalCount) devuelve undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes comprobar el tipo de dato

```
console.log(typeof this.Header)
```

el resultado debe string, entonces debes usar `JSON.parse`

```
this.Header=JSON.parse(this.Header)
```

y ahora comprueba `console.log(this.Header.TotalCount)`

Comment: tienes razon en efecto era un string y no un json, tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda, gracias